# Java Apache Pair Serializes in one format and Deserializes in different format using Jackson Serialize

Tags: java, json, apache, rest, jackson

When serialising `Apache Mutable Pair` using the `Jackson` `@JsonSerialize` annotation, this is the structure generated

```
{"leftValue": "rightValue"}
```

but for processing during deserialisation using `Jackson` `@JsonDeserialize` annotation, it expects this structure

```
{
"left":"leftValue",
"right": "rightValue"
}
```

Methods like `getLeft()` or `getValue()` return `null` when the first structure is used but return the correct values in case of the second structure.

How can it be serialised into the second structure? Also which is the recommended structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.MutablePair` extends `Pair` which implements `Map.Entry` interface. `Map.Entry` by default is treated by `Jackson` like a `Map` object which is serialised to `JSON` as `key-value` structure. To serialise it like a classical `POJO` we need to implement custom serialiser which will define proper structure:

```
class MutablePairJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MutablePair> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(MutablePair value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField("left", value.getLeft());
        gen.writeObjectField("right", value.getRight());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Simple app which uses above serialiser:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.MutablePair;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MutablePair<String, String> pair = new MutablePair<>();
        pair.setLeft("leftV");
        pair.setRight("rightV");

        SimpleModule pairModule = new SimpleModule();
        pairModule.addSerializer(MutablePair.class, new MutablePairJsonSerializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.registerModule(pairModule);

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(pair);
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, MutablePair.class));
    }
}
```

prints:

```
{
  "left" : "leftV",
  "right" : "rightV"
}
(leftV,rightV)
```

Which shows that object is serialised with keys and deserialised properly to object.

If, we wan to keep default serialisation process we need to customise deserialiser which could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.MutablePair;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MutablePair<String, String> pair = new MutablePair<>();
        pair.setLeft("leftV");
        pair.setRight("rightV");

        SimpleModule pairModule = new SimpleModule();
        pairModule.addDeserializer(MutablePair.class, new MutablePairJsonDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.registerModule(pairModule);

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(pair);
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, MutablePair.class));
    }
}

class MutablePairJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MutablePair> {

    @Override
    public MutablePair deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        p.nextToken(); // SKIP START_OBJECT
        String keyName = p.getCurrentName();
        p.nextToken();

        return MutablePair.of(keyName, p.getValueAsString());
    }
}
```